# Show NetBIOS name before Username on Windows 7 Logon

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, domain-controller, netbios

I am setting up a new DC using Windows Server 2008 R2, and my FQDN is MFC.com. When I logon to a client computer (E5530.MFC.com) using that domain, instead of showing "MFC\user.name", it shows "E5530\user.name".

How can I get the logon screen to show "MFC\user.name", instead of the computers' name at logon?

To make myself clear, I want my client logon screen to show "MFC\user.name".

Answer (score 0):

After you log in as "MFC\user.name" and then log out, does it still show "E5530\user.name"?

Also, is there a local user with the same username as the domain user?
If so, would you consider changing one of those? so that you may be able to login directly as user.name and it won't change need "MFC\" before it.

Comment: It always shows "E5530\user.name". There is no local user. I just want it to show "MFC\username"